# Detect empty string in numeric field using Cerberus

Tags: python, validation, cerberus

I am using the python library cerberus (http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/) and I want to check if a JSON field is a number (integer) or an empty string.

I tried using the condition:

```
{"empty": True, "type": "intenger"}
```

But when the field is an empty string, for example: (""), I get the following error.

```
'must be of integer type'
```

Is there a way of using the basic validation rules so it detects also an empty string in a numeric field?, I know it can be done by using extended validation functions but I want to avoid that solution for the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
{"anyof":[
   {"type":"string","allowed":[""]},
   {"anyof_type":["float","integer"]}
]},
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advise to not overcomplicate schemas. 1) Multiple types can be declared for the `type` rule. 2) The `empty` rule is only applied to sizable values, so it would ignore any given integer. Hence this is the simplest possible rules set for your constraints:

```
{'type': ('integer', 'string'),
 'empty': True}
```

Mind that this doesn't enforce the value to be an empty string, but allows it to be, vulgo: a non-empty string would also pass. You may want to use the `max_lengh` rule w/ `0` as constraint instead.